# Merging dataframes by date range & repeating a categorical column in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two dataframes:

df1 :

```
Time             A   B
1469510289000   1.5 2.4
1469510290000   2.5 7.1
1469510291000   2.2 6.4
1469510292000   1.4 2.3
1469510293000   1.6 1.8
1469510294000   2.2 4.1
1469510295000   1.2 0.6
```

and so on...

df2:

```
start             end         Category
1469510289000   1469510291000   A
1469510291000   1469510294000   B
1469510294000   1469510295000   A
1469510295000   NA              C
```

Time in both dataframes is in epoch. Now, I want to merge the df1 & df2, based on start & end column from df2, with category. The final resultant dataframe looks like this(df1):

```
Time             A  B  Category
1469510289000   1.5 2.4 A
1469510290000   2.5 7.1 A
1469510291000   2.2 6.4 B
1469510292000   1.4 2.3 B
1469510293000   1.6 1.8 B
1469510294000   2.2 4.1 A
1469510295000   1.2 0.6 C
```

Able to solve it by converting category into float by using np.peicewise but how can I do it when my category is text or an object? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean "object" but .. I think if you mean that the category is in string type, you can convert those data frame into list, in a list the string part will automatically become this form --> 'string', and append the category label to the corresponding list , probably may get you what you want.

Like this

```
df1:
 time  A    B
  1  1.5  2.4
  2  2.5  7.1
  3  2.2  6.4
  4  1.4  2.3
  5  1.6  1.8
  6  2.2  4.1
  7  1.2  0.6

df2:
start  end   category
  1     3    sthtxt1
  3     6    sthtxt2
  6     7    sthtxt1
  7    NA          C

F1 = df1.values.tolist()
F2 = df2.values.tolist()

for item1 in F1:
    for item2 in F2:
        if item1[0] >= item2[0] and item1[0] < item2[1]:
            item1.append(item2[2])

whatuwant=pd.DataFrame(F1)

whatuwant:
 time    A    B  category
  1.0  1.5  2.4  sthtxt1
  2.0  2.5  7.1  sthtxt1
  3.0  2.2  6.4  sthtxt2
  4.0  1.4  2.3  sthtxt2
  5.0  1.6  1.8  sthtxt2
  6.0  2.2  4.1  sthtxt1
  7.0  1.2  0.6        C
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant String by object. This is not working & giving me "none" in the category column with multiple category columns.

Comment: Are df1 and df2 pd.dataframe or they're just data files?

Comment: Yes, both are pd.DataFrame. I'm getting the output but it's making multiple columns after every category change.

Comment: Sry but I don't really understand your problem now lol Can you show me what you got??

Comment: Sorry, if it's unclear. I'm getting the output like(multiple columns): category1 = ['sthtxt1','sthtxt1',....,'sthtxt1'], category2 = ['sthtxt1','sthtxt1','sthtxt2','sthtxt2',....,'sthtxt2'] & so on... I hope this helps in understanding.

Comment: So in the example you gave, there are 3 category changes and the output you got is a data frame with A, B, cat1, cat2, cat3, totally 5 columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do I need to use pd.concat after append to solve this issue ?

Comment: No need. I edited my answer a little bit, now it's exactly how my code looks like. print the "whatuwant" part will get you the output.
Not sure what's going wrong but maybe you should check your loop, see if there's something strange in the item1.append part.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you ?

```
list = []
for time in df1['Time']:
     category = None
     count=-1
     for start,end in zip(df2['start'],df2['end']):
         count += 1
         if ( time>=start and time <= end):
             break
     if count != -1:
         category = df2.ix[count]['Category']
     list.append(category)
df1['Category']=list
df1
     A    B           Time Category
0  1.5  2.4  1469510289000        A
1  2.5  7.1  1469510290000        A
2  2.2  6.4  1469510291000        A
3  1.4  2.3  1469510292000        B
4  1.6  1.8  1469510293000        B
5  2.2  4.1  1469510294000        B
6  1.2  0.6  1469510295000        A
```